# How to tell ionic template that component methods are optional?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I have a component which includes ionic's ion-searchbar.
**ecHeaderInput** is an @input.
I can pass into **searchProps** any number of methods (ionInputMethod, ionCancelMethod, ionClearMethod, keyupEnterMethod), but I do not want to  to pass all methods every time I use the component (since I may not need all).
If I don't pass all methods, I get an error.
How can I tell the template that the methods are optional, or only define the method if it exists in  **ecHeaderInput.searchProps**?

```
<ion-searchbar *ngIf="ecHeaderInput.showSearch" 
[placeholder]="ecHeaderInput.searchProps.placeholder"[(ngModel)]="_searchTerm" 
[showCancelButton]="ecHeaderInput.searchProps.showCancelButton"  
(ionInput)="ecHeaderInput.searchProps.ionInputMethod(_searchTerm) 
ecHeaderInput.searchProps.ionInputMethod(_searchTerm)"  
(ionCancel)="ecHeaderInput.searchProps.ionCancelMethod(_searchTerm)"  
(ionClear)="ecHeaderInput.searchProps.ionClearMethod(_searchTerm)"  
(keyup.enter)="ecHeaderInput.searchProps.keyupEnterMethod(_searchTerm)"> </ion-
searchbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try as shown below.

**Property bindings:**

**Note:** For clarity, I get just one property:

*parent.html*

```
<ion-searchbar *ngIf="ecHeaderInput.showSearch" 
[placeholder]="ecHeaderInput.searchProps.placeholder"[(ngModel)]="_searchTerm"> 
</ion-searchbar>
```

You can use the ( `?` ) operator as below.

*child.ts*

```
export class IonSearchbarComponent {

    @Input() placeholder?: string;

    constructor() { }

}
```

Then you can use like this too:

```
<ion-searchbar *ngIf="ecHeaderInput.showSearch" [(ngModel)]="_searchTerm"> 
</ion-searchbar>
```

**Methods:**

Actually, you don't need to give all methods. You can see that on [**official doc here**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#searchbar).

*e.g.*

```
<ion-searchbar (ionInput)="getItems($event)"></ion-searchbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wait, You shouldn't get an error if a component has an @Output emitter but its parent is not using it and same goes for @Input. However, you will have an error if you are passing an input to a child component which has not declared that input. if your component has many @Outputs to choose from then you can either

1- Chose which one to use without having to define a function for each one of them

2- Wrap your target component to merge all its methods into one

```
import { Component, Output, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'wrap-component',
  template : `<ion-searchbar 
               (ionInput)="method1($event)"
               (ionCancel)="method2($event)"
               (etc)="etcetc($event)"
               ></ion-searchbar>`  
})
export class WrapComponent{
   @Input() arrayOfMethods:string[];
   @Output() mergeFunctionEmitter = new EventEmitter<any>();
   constructor(){}

   method1(someEvent){
      if(this.arrayOfMethods.indexOf('mehod1') > -1){
         this.mergeFunctionEmitter.emit(
             {
               method:"method1",
               data : someEvent
             }
         );
      }
   }
   method2(someEvent){
      if(this.arrayOfMethods.indexOf('mehod2') > -1){
         this.mergeFunctionEmitter.emit(
             {
               method:"method2",
               data : someEvent
             }
         );
      }
   }
   //etc etc as many methods as there are outputs

}
```

then throughout your app, you can call your WrapComponent and pass a list of methods you are interested in at that particular time through the @Input arrayOfMethods

```
<wrap-component 
     [arrayOfMethods]="['method1','method2']" 
     (onSomethingHasHappened)="mergeFunctionEmitter($event)">
</wrap-component>
```